# How to get Log4j log file absolute path in Java?

Tags: java, file, log4j

I am using Log4j to logging and log file path provided in Log4j.xml file. The web app will be deployed on weblogic server and log file is generating under home/JEE/servername/logs directory. Using java how to get this "../../logs/cast-arm.log" absolute path in Java?

log4j.xml (src\main\resources\log4j.xml)

```
<appender name="armFile" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="append" value="true" />
    <param name="maxFileSize" value="10MB" />
    <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="100" />
    <param name="file" value="../../logs/cast-arm.log" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern"  value="%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %c %x%n  %-5p %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Java:

```
File file = new File("../../logs");
```

Comment: Do you know this path ../../logs in java or that also needs to be found using program

Comment: Dear ravi, just in case you are the one who downvoted 10 of my highly rated answers at about the same time I suggested that you should delete an answer which was still false after two edits: Thanks for being such a gentleman. Do you feel better now? I suggest you grow up and learn to accept constructive criticism. I took the time to explain in detail what was incorrect about your answer. I did not mean to insult you. I was even polite, only honest.

Comment: By the way, StackOverflow corrected the votes because they were [detected as abusive serial voting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) automatically. If you apologise for the abuse in a little reply here, I am ready to delete this and the previous comment afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways you can get this absolute file path

1. Using `user.dir` property (*If you know the relative path*)

   ```
   File userDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));

   File logFile= new File(userDir , "../../logs/cast-arm.log");

   System.out.println(logFile.getAbsolutePath());
   ```
2. Using `FileAppender`

   ```
   FileAppender fileAppender = (FileAppender) logger.getRootLogger().getAppender("armFile");
   System.out.println(new File(fileAppender.getFile()).getAbsolutePath());
   ```

Hope this helps.